# How does wildcard ssl certificate match domains

Tags: ssl-certificate

In terms of wildcard ssl certificate, ***bar.example.net** would match domains like **foobar.example.net**, but will it also match **bar.example.net** ?

Answer (score 2):

First of all, `*bar.example.net` is not valid, it should be `*.bar.example.net`. This already advances the answer, which is: no, `*.bar.example.net` does not match `bar.example.net`.

Answer (score 0):

As Marcos said, you have to provide two entries for `domain.com` and `*.domain.com` which will cover for the main domain and any subdomain of the main domain.